# Как авторизоваться по API на python

Tags: python, api, post, auth, ldap

Собственно имеем вот такое описание, как авторизоваться:
https://support.huawei.com/view/contentview/getFileStream?mid=SUPE_DOC&viewNid=EDOC1000126989&nid=EDOC1000126989&partNo=j005&type=htm#ainterface-for-access-authentication

вот код:

```
import requests
import fake_useragent

data = {
    "username": "SDFE3ffgg@vid.ru",
    "password": "!FGSDSDSE##$$",
    "scope": "1"

}

url = 'https://192.168.100.23:8088/deviceManager/rest/3453567BVD10HA000034/sessions'

s = requests.Session()
login = s.post(url, data)

print(login)
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exporter.py", line 14, in <module>
    login = s.post(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 577, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 651, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.100.23', port=8088): Max retries exceeded with url: /deviceManager/rest/3453567BVD10HA000034/sessions (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnec
```

Куда копать, что не так делаю?

Comment: А попробуйте отправить как json: `login = s.post(url, json=data)`. Кст, там точно не надо сертификат указывать?

Comment: в api доке вроде написано, что надо указывать в post, а в итоге не получается. с json=data , так же

Comment: Ну да, вы правы, такая ошибка более низкого уровня, чем параметры запроса. У той машины по адресу 192.168.100.23 браудмаузер правильно настроен? Мб ли быть что блокируется подключение к порту 8088?

Comment: @gil9red , у меня теперь следующая ошибка, логин и пароль корректные, {u'data': {}, u'error': {u'code': 1073793541, u'description': u'The authenticati
on by the domain server fails.', u'suggestion': u'1. Enter the correct configura
tions of the domain authentication server.  \n2. Use a domain user on the domain
 server for login.'}}
<Response [200]>

Comment: А что вы сделали, чтобы дальше той ошибки прошел запрос?

Comment: @gil9red, запустил с другой машины, где хост был доступен этот

Comment: Насчет, последней ошибки... смотрите в `u'suggestion':` там есть варианты, либо спросите у поддержки